# Inserting variable into img url with echo

Tags: php

```
$playername = $_GET["playername"];
echo '<img src="https://cravatar.eu/head/SecretAgent5555"/>';
```

I need what SecretAgent5555 is to be $playername, plz help/

Comment: This question must be formulated in another way, because in reality what you want is to concatenate strings of characters, also a valid answer to this is very easy to find in the PHP documentation https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php

Answer (score 1):

This will do what you need...

`echo '<img src="https://cravatar.eu/head/' . $playername . '"/>';`

This uses the PHP `.` string concatenation feature to 'insert' `$playername` into the `img src` tag.

You can also use string interpolation by using double quotes, but it requires you to escape the double quotes within, like this.

`echo "<img src=\"https://cravatar.eu/head/$playername\"/>";`

Because you have opened the string being `echo`ed with the double quotes, to put a double quote within, you need to escape them. This is the `\"` part within the string.